# app/Apbuild.grandle error in my Flutter apps

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

*
I am starting to develop in Flutter (IDE: Android Studio) and whenever I want to modify the app / build.gradle
make mistakes in

```
def localProperties = new  Properties()
```

and

```
def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')

if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.") 
}
```

I know it does not affect compiling the application but it is very annoying that the app / bradle is underlined in red

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to remove the exception. However, the problem is probably due to insufficient permissions on the folder where flutter was installed. Make sure you have the right permissions.

Finally you can rewrite your build.gradle files to not have the exception by replacing parts of them with the following:

#### android/build.gradle

```
subprojects {
    buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    beforeEvaluate {
        def localProps = new Properties().tap { prop ->
            File localPropsFile = getRootProject().file('local.properties')
            if (localPropsFile.exists()) {
                localPropsFile.withReader("utf-8") {
                    prop.load(it)
                }
            }
        }

        localProps.stringPropertyNames().each { key ->
            ext[key] = localProps.getProperty(key)
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially what this does is to read the `local.properties` file (if it exists) and create the properties read from it, in the subproject's namespace. We are basically emulating what gradle does with the `gradle.properties` file.

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
ext {
    flutterRoot = properties.'flutter.sdk'
    flutterVersionCode = properties.'flutter.versionCode' ?: '1'
    flutterVersionName = properties.'flutter.versionName' ?: '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

... // everything else is pretty much the same from here
```

Now in the subproject, we can access those properties using the project's properties. The above replaces that hideous smorgasbord of if-statements, with something a little more gradle-like.